Outbound Calls via WebRTC
I keep getting an error 45301 when making outbound calls. This is intermittent across my agents on the floor but Twilio keeps pointing this to a connection issue though I have changed internet connections

I tried a few steps by changing connections via WiFi and even hotspotted from my phone to eliminate the connection issue. I also changed browsers even switched to incognito on Chrome and Edge but I get the same issues
